# how to substract days from current day on blade template in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

```
<span>{{ is_numeric($a->duration) - \Carbon\Carbon::parse($a->created_at)->diffForHumans() }} days left</span>
```

Comment: What is the issue you're facing? Errors? Unexpected results?

Answer (score 1):

you should probably create accessor in model like this

```php
function getDaysLeftAttribute()
{
    $created_at = \Carbon\Carbon::parse($this->created_at);
    return $created_at->subDays((int)$this->duration)->diffForHumans();
}
```

then in blade you can do this

```php
<span>{{ $a->days_left }} days left</span>
```

ref link

https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-difference

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor

Comment: Duration is a numeric value

Comment: @PrakashThapa okay check now

Answer (score 0):

If you are just looking for substracting the days from current date then it's pretty simple  you just have to do this in your blade

```
{{now()->subDays(2)}}
```

Replace the 2 with the amount of days which you want to substract